# Multiple Python Plots Not Showing Plots in Other Subplots

Tags: python, matplotlib, subplot

I wrote a code to automatically plot multiple grid subplots based on number of cells available, I did the following:

```
cell=10
ax = {}
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))


for subgrd in range(cell):

    if subgrd < cell / 2:
        for subgrd2 in range(int(cell / 2)):
            key = 'ax' + str(subgrd)
            value = plt.subplot2grid((2, int(cell / 2)), (0, subgrd2))
            ax[key] = value

    else:
        for subgrd2 in range(int(cell / 2)):
            key = 'ax' + str(subgrd)
            value = plt.subplot2grid((2, int(cell / 2)), (1, subgrd2))
            ax[key] = value
print("count ax",len(ax))
for axval in range(len(ax)):
    print(str(axval))
    ax['ax'+str(axval)].plot([[1,2],[4,3]])
    ax['ax'+str(axval)].axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax['ax'+str(axval)].axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Somehow the above code is only showing the data on two plots, don't know why?

[image]

Comment: For one, insert `print("if", cell, subgrd, subgrd2)` and `print("else", cell, subgrd, subgrd2)` to see that the script is not doing what you think it is doing. Which explains why the dictionary does not contain what you think it contains.

Comment: @Mr.T It makes soo much sense now! thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your nested for loop is replacing the contents of the `ax` dictionary from earlier columns. Get rid of the nested loop, and calculate the row and column based on `subgrd`. That way, you only assign each key once.

```
cell=10
ax = {}
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))

row_count = 2
column_count = (cell+row_count-1) // row_count
for subgrd in range(cell):
    row = subgrd // column_count
    column = subgrd % column_count
    key = 'ax' + str(subgrd)
    value = plt.subplot2grid((row_count, column_count), (row, column))
    ax[key] = value

print("count ax",len(ax))
for axval in range(len(ax)):
    print(str(axval))
    ax['ax'+str(axval)].plot([[1,2],[4,3]])
    ax['ax'+str(axval)].axes.xaxis.set_visible(False)
    ax['ax'+str(axval)].axes.yaxis.set_visible(False)

plt.show()
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I guess I need more coffee :)